# MFMailComposeViewController throws an error only in iOS 9

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios9

I can't get MFMailComposeViewController to open without throwing a fatal error in iOS 9 Simulator.

The same code (Objective C) works flawlessly in iOS 8.x and lower but today I installed Xcode 7 beta 5 and when I run the app on iOS 9 Simulator, I get a dialog box titled "MailCompositionService quit unexpectedly" and when I view the error report, I see:

> Application Specific Information:
> *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[__NSArrayI isEqualToString:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7fd314280b10'
>
> terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
> abort() called
> CoreSimulator 179 - Device: iPhone 6 - Runtime: iOS 9.0 (13A4325c) - DeviceType: iPhone 6

The error happens when the mail composition view comes up. It freezes for a few seconds and then the error dialog box comes up.

The code that opens the mail composition view is:

```
if ([MFMailComposeViewController canSendMail])
{
    MFMailComposeViewController *picker = [[MFMailComposeViewController alloc] init];
    picker.mailComposeDelegate = self;
    [picker setSubject:@"Comment title"];
    [picker setMessageBody:@"Comment description" isHTML:NO];
                                        
    [self.window.rootViewController presentModalViewController:picker animated:YES];
    [picker release];
}
```

If it helps to know, before the app crashes, `mailComposeController:didFinishWithResult:error:` is called with `result` = `MFMailComposeResultCancelled` and `error` = `nil`.

I'd appreciate tips on how to find the cause of this error. Thanks!

Comment: Test on a real (development) device where you know that mail works properly.

Comment: Thanks! I will test on a dev device and report back.

Comment: @rmaddy, I did test on a real device and it works. Thanks for the tip! Please put your answer in a post so I tag it as the correct one.

Comment: I would suppose that's a bug on iOS 9, possibly because mail has not been set up. I can't even find a setting on the iOS 9 simulator where you can set up an email account. IIRC this also crashed on iOS 6 or 7 or so...

Comment: As of XCode 7.2/iOS 9.2 simulator, this is still happening. Per https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/4415 it looks like a known bug. Of course the [opacity of Apple's bug reporting system](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/144873/can-i-browse-other-peoples-apple-bug-reports) means we have no idea if it's gotten any love or not. Hard to believe this is still an issue!

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The issue is with simulator, on the real device mail composer is working correctly.

Comment: Do you know if this would have a negative effect when publishing? I read somewhere that Apple might reject your update/app because they run it on simulator and thus the app would not function correctly, but I don't know whether this is true.

Comment: I just can tell you that I have apps published on Apple Store that have this issue on simulator. In my experience Apple never rejected my apps because of this issue.

Comment: @EdwinLambregts Apple doesn't review the apps using the Simulator - this is impossible anyway as the binary you submit has not been built for i386 / x86_64

Answer (score 5):

As per Apple Developer Forum, more details are [here](https://forums.developer.apple.com/message/93492#93492).

> The simulator doesn't support mail. You should likely try testing mail
>   functionality in a device.

Comment: Thanks for linking to the Apple Dev Forum!

Answer (score 1):

You should use :
`[self.window.rootViewController presentViewController:picker animated:YES completion:NULL];`
presentModalViewController is DEPRECATED since ios6 is and has been replaced by  `presentViewController:animated:completion:`
ie:
    - `(void)presentModalViewController:(UIViewController *)modalViewController animated:(BOOL)animated NS_DEPRECATED_IOS(2_0, 6_0);`

Comment: Thanks for the tip @Idali. Point taken, though in this case as I mentioned above the problem was caused by something else.

Comment: issue is not fixed yet now, in 9.2

Answer (score 0):

I have no idea why it happens or how did I discovered it, the crash seems to be generated by setting the NSFontAttributeName in the Appearance proxy for the navigation bar, if I uncomment that line the app crashes.

```
    NSDictionary* format = @{
                         NSForegroundColorAttributeName:[UIColor whiteColor],
                         //NSFontAttributeName: [UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:20],
                         };

[[UINavigationBar appearance] setTitleTextAttributes:format];
```

Please @Sleiman try and see if this fixes the issue for you too.

Comment: the solution that worked for me is to do the simulation on a real device. I don't have `NSFontAttributeName` statements.

Comment: In my case it was also crashing on the device :(

Comment: I can confirm, it stops crashing after removing that line

Answer (score 0):

As a simple work around for this problem, you can use "mailto" protocol, it will:

- Not crash the app (device and simulator)
- Prompt the user to login if the device has not login with any mail account

[image]

Example in swift:

**Swift 3.0**

```
let mailRecipient = "support@abc.com"
let mailSubject = "Help with ABC for iOS"
let mailBody = "xxx"

let mailTo = "mailto:\(mailRecipient)?subject=\(mailSubject)&body=\(mailBody)"

guard let escapedMailTo = mailTo.addingPercentEncoding(withAllowedCharacters: .urlQueryAllowed) else {
    NSLog("Invalid mail to format")
    return
}

guard let url = NSURL(string: escapedMailTo) else {
    NSLog("Invalid mail to format: \(escapedMailTo)")
    return
}

UIApplication.sharedApplication().openURL(url)
```

**Swift 2.3**

```
let mailRecipient = "support@abc.com"
let mailSubject = "Help with ABC for iOS"
let mailBody = "xxx"

let mailTo = "mailto:\(mailRecipient)?subject=\(mailSubject)&body=\(mailBody)"

guard let escapedMailTo = mailTo.stringByAddingPercentEncodingWithAllowedCharacters(.URLQueryAllowedCharacterSet()) else {
    NSLog("Invalid mail to format")
    return
}

guard let url = NSURL(string: escapedMailTo) else {
    NSLog("Invalid mail to format: \(escapedMailTo)")
    return
}

UIApplication.sharedApplication().openURL(url)
```